# Programmatically calling drag event from function draggable() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-draggable

I have following code in Javascript file.
I need to trigger the drag event programmatically but I am not able to.

```
$(".toolItems").draggable({
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        alert();
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        removeToolItem(event, ui);
    }
});
```

I am trying to call it in following manner

```
function createEvt1() {
    var evt1 = $.Event('drag');
    evt1.clientX = 20;
    evt1.clientY = 30;
    $('.toolItems').trigger("drag",evt1);
}
```

but it is not working

Comment: What does "I need to trigger the drag event pragmatically" mean?

Comment: means i need to trigger it without help of mouse.

Comment: Do you need to have it trigger regularly, or on page load?

Comment: not on page load. i need to trigger it only when i call a function

Answer (score 0):

Just make a function and put the drag event inside of it?

```
function enabledrag(){
    $(".toolItems").draggable({
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            alert();
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            removeToolItem(event, ui);
        }
    });
}

function createEvt1() {
    var evt1 = $.Event('drag');
    evt1.clientX = 20;
    evt1.clientY = 30;
    enabledrag();
}
```

Comment: i have tried this in unti testing but noting is getting fired

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function createEvt1() {
    var evt1 = $.Event('drag');
    evt1.clientX = 20;
    evt1.clientY = 30;
    makeDraggable('.toolItems');
 }

function makeDraggable(selector){
    $(selector).draggable({
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            alert("dragging");
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            alert("stopping");
        }
    });
}
```